# How can I get "this->" by inputting "this."?

Tags: yasnippet, abbrev

I want to input `this.` and get `this->` in c++-mode.

I tried `abbrev-mode` and `yasnippet`, but failed.

In abbrev-mode, I defined an abbrev `this` to get `this` using `.` as a trigger key, but soon as I typed `this.` I got `this->.`.

In yasnippet, I defined a snippet

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: this
# key: this
# binding: .
# condition: (eq 0 (string-match "this" (buffer-substring (- (point) 4) (point))))
# --
this->
```

but got `thisthis->` after input `this.`.

If I remove the `this` in the last line of the snippet

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: this
# key: this
# binding: .
# condition: (eq 0 (string-match "this" (buffer-substring (- (point) 4) (point))))
# --
->
```

everything seems fine but why we don't need `this` here ? Also, under this situation, the expansion broke the completion of `company-irony` even I've added `yas-expand` to `irony-completion-trigger-commands`.

What is the ***simplest*** way to achieve this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

From abbrev [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Abbrevs.html#Abbrevs) (emphasis mine):

> A defined “abbrev” is a **word** which “expands”, if you insert it, into
>   some different text.

`this.` is not a word, at least in `c++-mode` so this can't work.

My suggestion is to rebind in c++-mode the `.` key to a command testing if the current word is `this`, and inserting `->` if so, `.` otherwise.

As pointed by @npostavs it's better to call `self-insert-command` in the second case, rather than simply calling `(insert ".")` as this ensures the processing is exactly what it was before we changed the binding.  For example a [prefix argument](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html#Arguments), if any, is handled as expected.

```el
(defun this-dot-replace ()
  (interactive)
  (if (string= (thing-at-point 'word) "this")
      (insert "->")
    (call-interactively 'self-insert-command)))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook
  (lambda () (define-key c++-mode-map "." 'this-dot-replace)))
```

I make no guarantee this (pun intended?) is the simplest possible way.

Comment: This is basically what the 2nd yasnippet in the question does (but maybe this method won't have problems with `company-irony`?), which explains why `this` needs to be removed from the snippet body. You might want to `(call-interactively 'self-insert-command)` in the else branch.

Comment: @npostavs Yes indeed. I don't use yasnippet so I didn't realize that.  What would be the advantage of calling `self-insert-command`? (I understand this is what happens when the key is not rebound).

Comment: It probably doesn't matter much, but `self-insert-command` handles a prefix argument. (Also, I think some extensions look at `this-command` to see if it's `self-insert-command` and might do different things in that case)

Comment: @npostavs Good point.  I updated the answer.

Comment: @JeanPierre Thanks for you answer and sorry for late reply ! I mean `this` is an abbrev and use `.` as a trigger key. I try your function but it seems that it also has problem with `company-irony` and won't trigger completion even I 've added `insert`(which is used in the `if` case) to `irony-completion-trigger-commands`.